# Mvvmcross Location Plugin current and last seen locations are null

Tags: xamarin, gps, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to get location in my application using mvvmcross location plugin, but it's always throw null reference exception because `CurrentLocation` and `LastSeenLocation` are always null. GPS service is enabled on real android device and permisions has been configured in android manifest. I've tested app on genymotion, and if I turn on GPS it works. I can't understand, why location provider doesn't provide location on real device.
Here is code sample:

```
 private void GetLocation()
    {
        IMvxLocationWatcher _locationWatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxLocationWatcher>();
        _locationWatcher.Start(new MvxLocationOptions() {Accuracy = MvxLocationAccuracy.Fine}, OnLocation, OnError );
        try
        {
            Lat = _locationWatcher.CurrentLocation.Coordinates.Latitude;
            Lng = _locationWatcher.CurrentLocation.Coordinates.Longitude;
        }
        catch
        {
            Lat = _locationWatcher.LastSeenLocation.Coordinates.Longitude;
            Lng = _locationWatcher.LastSeenLocation.Coordinates.Longitude;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Android is on the device?

Comment: @Giorgi There are several divices which I have tested: 4.1.1, 4.2.2, 4.4.2, 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location information is available only after the `OnLocation` callback is called. For example here is one way to get the location:

```
private void GetLocation()
{
    IMvxLocationWatcher _locationWatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxLocationWatcher>();
    _locationWatcher.Start(new MvxLocationOptions() {Accuracy = MvxLocationAccuracy.Fine}, (location) => {
        // Use location parameter to get location information}, 
     OnError);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is OnLocation starts when location changed? For example: I need to get location and send it when button has been pressed. But if device doesn't change location, OnLocation would not start.